# Backside of object will not get dark, why not?

Tags: rendering, lighting, world, ambient-occlusion

I put only one spotlight to the left side of my photo setup and the ambience light (world) is set to full black. Ambient occlusion is at 0.33 and 120 m distance. Why does my object get light from the right side, when it should be almost black, similar to the preview in layout mode? There is no light coming from the right. I tried all types of nodes as described in similar questions here on this site but nothing comes near to the desired effect. I'm using version 2.9.2.

[image: rendered view]
[image: settings and preview in layout mode]

Comment: are you sure your other lights are disabled for render? in the Outliner dropdown menu, enable the camera icon to check. If it's not the problem, it may be the indirect light even though it seems a bit strong...

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out,because what moonboots already mentioned is totally right, but we cannot see on your screenshot because of your settings the screenshot doesn't show whether it will be rendered or not

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This shadow cannot be made if there is no light source at back side of the chair.

[image]

And given that there are multiple lights in your collection, I think you deactivated `viewport visibility`(Eye icon) only. Click the [Filter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html#filter) icon, and click the "Camera" button to see `render visibility`.

If it's on, object will be seen in the render. Turn off the "Camera" button to disalbe the light in render.

[image]
[image]

Comment: 2D Snubby, you saved my day! This was exactly the problem I faced and now i could solve it the way you showed me. Thanks a lot!